# Subtracting Values from Different Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, difference, between

I have two tables:

```
Table A
ID  Number Profile
1   100     Baker
2   75      Fields
3   100     Wayward

Table B
ID  Number Tag  Sender
1   50      on  chris
2   50      off james
```

What I am try to do subtract the values from Table A and Table B who has the same ID numbers

```
Table C
ID  Number
1   50
2   25
```

Comment: Welcome to S/O.  Although the one answer supplied will do what you asked, the bigger question is what happens if either table has more than one row in each respective table.  That can and will throw-off your results via a Cartesian product.  In future, edit existing posts and try to supply even a little background vs just here's table A and B.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.ID,A.NUMBER-B.NUMBER DIFF
FROM TABLE_A AS A
JOIN TABLE_B AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
```